# Django @login_required decorator with non-constant string throws exception

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I decorate my protected pages with a `@login_required(login_url=login_url)`

When, at the top of my `views.py` file, I set `login_url=reverse("member_login")` it throws an exception:

```
Tried tag_index in module dgn.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'tag_index'
```

`tag_index` is the last item in the URL dispatcher list. If I comment that out then it simply throws the exception mentioning the one before it.

The strange thing is, when I set the `login_url="constant/string/to/path"`, then it works just fine. Obviously, `login_url=reverse('member_login')` is messing it up. I use reverse in many other places inside functions in the views.py file, and make sure to name each entry in the URL dispatch list.

Any help about what could be the problem would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLConf is not loaded yet at that point.
Use [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-lazy), if you have django 1.4

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense than my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing anything from views.py in your urls.py file? If so you might have circular import issues, and you might need to rejig urls.py so it doesn't need the import.